# How do I fix "this range cannot be published due to an internal error" when trying to create a list from an excel file?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, excel-services

I have tried making sure there are no formulas in the file. I have started with a fresh file. I have checked the trusted sites in internet explorer. I am trying to upload from my users download folder. Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

I used the Repair feature from the Change button in Windows Programs and Features and it appeared to resolve the problem. I have had to do this when exporting a list to Excel and getting a different error.